# Что будет если вызвать синхронную функцию в асинхронной?

Tags: python, асинхронность

Изменится ли скорость если вызвать в асинхронной функции синхронную?

```
    async def sad():
           wer = werti()
           print(wer)

    def werti():
         x = 80
         return x
```

Comment: Какой код вы напишите в синхронной функции, с такой скоростью и будет работать

Answer (score 0):

Скорость зависит от сложности функции, но лучше использовать async в async для предотвращения блокировки событийного цикла.

Если вызывать синхронную функцию внутри асинхронной - получим паузу в `event loop`'e, т.к. весь `event loop` будет ждать завершения синхронной функции.

Для того, чтобы не блокировать `event loop` синхронной функцией используют метод - `loop.run_in_executor(...)`, [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).

Пример:

```
async def sad():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, werti)
    print(result)
```